# Transform date function language

Tags: php

I'm new to php.
I hope you can help me .. I have a date_format function, which gives as value "13 April, 2019", I need to translate the months into Spanish. I have searched before posting here, but I have not found the answer.

I have tried to modify 'd-m-Y H: i: s' but I do not get any change on the delivered date.

This is the function:

```
public function get_job_added_publish_date() {

            $date_format = get_option('date_format');

            $date_format = $date_format != '' ? $date_format : 'd-m-Y H:i:s';

            $job_publish_date = get_post_meta($this->job_id, 'jobsearch_field_job_publish_date', true);

            $job_publish_date = isset($job_publish_date) && $job_publish_date != '' ? date($date_format, $job_publish_date) : '';

            return $job_publish_date;

        }
```

I just need the month to be shown in Spanish, not in English.

Comment: [`Date::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) doesn't know foreign languages. [`strftime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) knows but configuring it is not straightforward (and depends on the OS) and the results also depend on the OS. There probably is a library out there that can do the work for you...

Comment: You probably need to use [setlocale](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) before formatting the date to get the month in the language you need.